# Select rows based on non-equality, using just one condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose a table has a column `num` of type `INT` and the values in that column are allowed to be `NULL`. Now, provided that some rows has `num` cell set to some value and it's `NULL` for other rows, how do I select all the rows where `num` is not equal to a specific value, *including* the rows where `num` is `NULL`, using just one condition?

For example, if the `num` value I wanted to exclude from selection was `5`, I would have to use a `SELECT` query with two conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `num` != 5 OR `num` IS NULL;
```

But how to make this simple retrieval using just one condition?

Comment: I can't think of any solution... Why is the two conditions-thing wrong? Maybe take a look at IN? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: @Tim Performance reasons

Comment: Then IN will not help you.

Comment: Get rid of the NULL values.

    `UPDATE instable SET num = 0 WHERE num IS NULL;`

Make sure the column `num` has an index. Then you can play.
You also say you have performance problems, but fail to mention any details about the amount of data/rows in your table.

Comment: @Perleone Well I wish I could say "Yay!" but I need `NULL` values in my actual table and the `INT` type is there only for the sake of example, in my actual table it's not `INT`.

Comment: How many rows does your actual table have? Why won't an index on that row help your performance issues?

Comment: @Perleone This is getting off topic. If the answer to my question is "It's not possible with one condition" then so be it, I'll move on.

Comment: One condition does not necessarily mean better performance that two conditions with an `OR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this will help you.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ifnull(`num`,0) != 5;
```